# How I yum install postgres using rpm from http://yum.postgresql.org?

Tags: postgresql

How I yum install postgres using rpm from http://yum.postgresql.org?

I followed these steps:

Install Centos 6.5 from Live DVD:

http://vault.centos.org/6.5/isos/x86_64

I google: Postgres 9.5 install on Centos 6.5

I run two shell commands:

```
wget https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.5/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-centos95-9.5-2.noarch.rpm
yum install pgdg-centos95-9.5-2.noarch.rpm
```

I'm not sure what to do next.

I see this page:

http://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php

At the top of the page is a link: 'Yum Howto'

I click that link and see this page:

http://yum.postgresql.org/howtoyum.php

The first link there is this:

http://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php

So I am seeing circular documentation rather than helpful documentation.

I see a link to a pdf:

http://yum.postgresql.org/files/PostgreSQL-RPM-Installation-PGDG.pdf

I open the pdf and it lists packages that are available.

I surmise that I need these packages:

postgresql-libs, postgresql and postgresql-server

It does not say where they are.

Questions:

Where are the packages listed in PostgreSQL-RPM-Installation-PGDG.pdf ?

Assuming I want to install: postgresql-libs, postgresql and postgresql-server, How to?

At postgresql.org, I see this rpm : pgdg-centos95-9.5-2.noarch.rpm

What is the purpose of pgdg-centos95-9.5-2.noarch.rpm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out.

The purpose of pgdg-centos95-9.5-2.noarch.rpm is to expose more packages to the yum-package-list on my host.

I can then see some of them with this command:

```
yum list postgresql95*
```

And I can install them with this command:

```
yum install postgresql95 postgresql95-server postgresql95-libs postgresql95-devel
```

I ran the above commands on my centos host and they worked perfectly.

Comment: That's a package that installs a repository, and without it `yum` is blind to the other source.